# Residue theorem integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm struggling to understand the concept of the residue theorem in integration using the residue theorem, can someone explain in this example.
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{3-2\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)} \,{\rm d}\theta$$

Comment: Have you learned the definitions of sine and cosine in complex analysis (e-powers)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please always include your own thoughts about the problem at hand - this will allow potential answerers to tailor their answer for your level of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Euler formulas $$\cos \theta = \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}\quad \sin \theta = \frac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$$ to write the integral as
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{3 - e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta} + \frac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}} \, d\theta$$ then multiply numerator and denominator by $ie^{i\theta}$ to arrive at $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{i\theta} d\theta}{3ie^{i\theta} - ie^{2i\theta} - i + \frac{e^{2i\theta} - 1}{2}}.$$
This equals the line integral $$\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{dz}{3iz - iz^2 - i + \frac{z^2 - 1}{2}}$$ when parametrized by $z = e^{i\theta}$. Now factor the denominator and use the Residue Theorem.

Comment: Did you factor the denominator?

Comment: i have trouble finding singularities and finding what's inside contour and where to identify the pole

Comment: That's why you should start by factoring the denominator.

Comment: @erf44 Have a look at the recent answer I made to a similar problem : (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2186117).

Comment: It looks like you got it. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

The best factorization of the denominator I can do is:
 $$3iz - iz^2 - i + \frac{z^2-1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} ((1+2i) - iz)(-1 + (2+i)z).$$