# evaluation of integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I do not fully understand how to use the residue theorem for evaluating integrals. Can someone evaluate the following integral using the residue theorem explaining step by step?

$$\int_\gamma \frac{e^{z\pi}}{z^2(z^2+2z+2)} \,dz$$
where $\gamma$ is circle of centre $0$ and radius $3$

Comment: I have recently given in (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2186117) a way to apply residue calculus on an example.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the zero of $z^2(z^2+2z+2)$.
2. Find the residue at the zeroes of ${e^{z\pi}\over{z^2+2z+2}}$ multiply them by $2i\pi$  and add the result.

Comment: ... only for the poles which are inside the contour...

Comment: ..but all the poles are inside the contour

Comment: Yes but I think that it must be said... to somebody who is a newcomer in this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)={e^{\pi z}}/({z^4+2z^3+2z^2})$. The poles of the function are at $z=0,-1\pm i$ and all three poles lie in the contour $\gamma:|z|=3$. To evaluate the integral we can use residue theorem.
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz = 2\pi i \sum\left[\text{residues of}\ f\ \text{inside}\ \gamma\right]$$
So we need to find the residues at all the poles.
$$\int_\gamma \frac{e^{\pi z}}{z^4+2z^3+2z^2}\ dz = 2\pi i\left(\mathrm{Res}(f,0)+\mathrm{Res}(f,-1+i)+\mathrm{Res}(f,-1-i)\right)$$
At $z=0$ the pole is of order $2$ so we can evaluate the residue using the formula for higher-order poles: If $z_0$ is a pole of order $n$, the residue of $f$ at $z_0$ is given by the following.
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,z_0)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left((z-z_0)^nf(z)\right)$$
In our case,
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{ze^{\pi z}}{z^2+2z+2}\right)=\frac{\pi-1}{2}$$
At $z=-1+i=\sqrt2 e^{3\pi i/4}$ the pole is simple and the residue for a simple pole is given by the following.
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)$$
In our case, we can use L'Hôpital's rule to find,
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,\sqrt2 e^{3\pi i/4})=\lim_{z\to \sqrt2 e^{3\pi i/4}}\left[\frac{e^{\pi z}(z-\sqrt2 e^{3\pi i/4})}{z^4+2z^3+2z^2}\right]=-\frac{1}{4e^{\pi}}$$
At $z=-1-i=\sqrt2 e^{5\pi i/4}$ the pole is simple as well.
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,\sqrt2 e^{5\pi i/4})=\lim_{z\to \sqrt2 e^{5\pi i/4}}\left[\frac{e^{\pi z}(z-\sqrt2 e^{5\pi i/4})}{z^4+2z^3+2z^2}\right]=-\frac{1}{4e^{\pi}}$$
Thus we have,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_\gamma \frac{e^{\pi z}}{z^4+2z^3+2z^2}\ dz &= 2\pi i \left(\mathrm{Res}(f,0)+\mathrm{Res}(f,-1+i)+\mathrm{Res}(f,-1-i)\right)\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{\pi - 1}{2}-\frac{1}{4e^{\pi}}-\frac{1}{4e^\pi}\right) \\
&=\pi i \left(\pi - e^{-\pi} - 1 \right).
\end{align*}$$